# parseInt rounding for number of days in month

Tags: javascript, date, rounding, parseint

Number of days in month calculated this way:

```
var start = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1);
var end = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,1);
var daysInCurMonth = parseInt((end-start)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

`d` is actual Date,for March it holds value(from FireBug console):
`Date {Thu Mar 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200}`

`parseInt((end-start)/(1000*60*60*24))` results **30**,but

`(end-start)/(1000*60*60*24)` results **30.958333333333332**

I expect rounding to **31**,when using `parseInt()` function.

`Math.round((end-start)/(1000*60*60*24))` results **31**,that is correct for March 2012.

Is it OK to rely on `Math.round()`,when dealing with dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far have you tested this? Does not seem 100% secure to me.

Take a look at this method: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2099

How I did it a while back, and it works very well :)

Comment: i'm also hesitating in its secureness,that's why asked the question)thank you for hint,I will check it

Comment: You could make a function out of it an running it for a few months, just to double-check with a real calendar. It might work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parseFloat` and `Math.round`
If you need the next integer you can use `Math.ceil`

Comment: do you mean use them together like `Math.round(parseFloat((end-start)/(1000*60*60*24)))`,because just parseFloat results float as well

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to rely on Math.round(),when dealing with dates?

No, it is NOT! Dates are not numbers, `today + 3600 * 24` is not always equal to `tomorrow`.

To find out days in the month use the following property of the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate):

> if you use 0 for dayValue, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month

so,

```
function daysInMonth(y, m)
{
    return new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();
}


alert(daysInMonth(2011,1)) // 28
alert(daysInMonth(2012,1)) // 29
```